# Validate credit card date format MM/yy to Valid Month and Year . Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying customer entered credit card expiration date which is in string in the format "MM/yy" to convert it into the valid month and year. So far I have tried `var result = DateTime.ParseExact("12/24", "MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  . I am not sure if this is the correct way. So, please guide me to find the right way to resolve it. Thank you in advance

Comment: And what is happening when you run that code? Is there a particular reason you believe that might not be the correct way?

Comment: This code works, and it is a correct way to do it. What's your issue?

Comment: when I enter 29 in the year section it converts it into 2029 but when I enter 30 it converts it into 1930 so I got confused.

Comment: @damonshahi - Looks at the [documentation for yy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yySpecifier). It says that it uses the [Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax?view=net-5.0) property. You could change that, but the better option would be to use a 4 digit year if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. When parsing two digit year you have to adjust the Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax.

The default calendar goes from 1930 to 2029 so, when parsing year 30, it assumes 1930.

Fix it using something like:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
ci.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099; // the end year, so it goes from 2000 to 2099.
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("12/30", "MM/yy", ci);
```